# How do I render a custom form in page--front.tpl.php?

Tags: theming, forms

I have a custom form with a button.

```
function mymodule_get_subscribed_form($form, $form_state) {
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
}
```

Now I want render this button on the front page. I've wrote this code in page--front.tpl.php.

```
print render(drupal_get_form('mymodule_get_subscribed_form'));
```

It doesn't work with Drupal 7.54, even after clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of variables being passed by reference. Try this instead:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('mymodule_get_subscribed_form');
print drupal_render($form);
```

Comment: I added
'mymodule_get_subscribed_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'file' => 'mymodule.pages.inc',
),
to mymodule_theme and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
'mymodule_get_subscribed_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'file' => 'mymodule.pages.inc',
),
```

to mymodule_theme hook and now it works.